# Zabbix Memory Used key

Tags: zabbix

I have an item that has vm.memory.size[used] as a key, this returns the memory used, this also included the cached and the buffers.

I need to subtract vm.memory.size[cached] and vm.memory.size[buffers] from the vm.memory.size[used] to get the value that I need.

How can I do this please since I cannot find a way to do this, this what I tried lately but deos not work.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you want to calculate it in a separate item, you must have `used`, `cached` and `buffers` already monitored as normal items. Once you have them, the [calculated item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) formula would be `last(vm.memory.size[used])-last(vm.memory.size[cached])-last(vm.memory.size[[buffers])` .

You can also calculate that directly in a trigger, removing the need for the calculated item.

And maybe even simpler than that - `vm.memory.size[available]` and `vm.memory.size[pavailable]` [item keys](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) can give you the (raw and percentage, respectively) amount of the available memory - already excluding cache & buffers - that you might be able to alert on directly.

Comment: Wow, this small answer could be two valid answers, each deserving its own an upvote...